# I tried to use flutter_bloc to check if a number is in the list but the list is changing but It's not Listening

Tags: flutter, bloc

now if I have Home Page and My Favorite Page and Favorite List variable in Locale Storage because i wont request to server every time to check if the product is in favorite or not, just request one time to get all id of my favorite and assign it to Favorite List,

And I have a IconButton on every product card with Favorite Icon, this Favorite Icon color must be Red if the Product Id is in the Favorites List and grey if not in the Favorite List.

Now if I added product from home to favorite by click on the IconButton of favorite it's must added to favorite List from home and the Favorite Icon of the IconButton become red then Navigated to the My Favorites Page  by using push and removed it from Favorite List then pop and back to Home, the favorite Icon of IconButton must be gray.

But this is not what happens the favorite Icon of IconButton still have the red color, so i want it listen to Favorite List, if the id of product removed from the Favorite List the  favorite Icon of IconButton color must change to grey.

So I tried to use BloC to do that, I created now Project to Test, and I tried many way like the code below but it's not works.

the code:

```
class FavosCubit extends Cubit<bool> {
  int id;
  FavosCubit(this.id) : super(favosId.contains(id));

  void toggle() {
    if (favosId.contains(id)) {
      favosId.remove(id);
    } else {
      favosId.add(id);
    }
    print(state) // works it's print true or false;
    return emit(favosId.contains(id));
  }
}
```

```
 BlocProvider<FavosCubit>(
          create: (BuildContext context) => FavosCubit(0),
        ),
```

```
 Column(
        children: [
          ...List.generate(
            6,
            (index) => BlocBuilder<FavosCubit, bool>(
              cubit: FavosCubit(index),
              builder: (context, state) {
                return IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.favorite,
                    color: state ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => context.bloc<FavosCubit>().toggle(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

the state is changing
now what i must do to make the view listening?